# Performance Bottleneck with IF NOT EXISTS Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists, sqlperformance

I'm encountering a significant performance difference when using an IF NOT EXISTS subquery within a larger query. The subquery executes quickly when run independently, taking approximately 2 seconds. However, when embedded within the larger query, the overall execution time increases dramatically to 4-5 minutes.

I've ensured that appropriate indexes are defined on the relevant tables, including the temporal table `nd.tblReqMatSum`. Note that `tmp.##mytable` is a global temporary table with no indexes, but it is almost always very small. Despite this, the performance issue persists.

Here's the problematic query:

```
declare @result int=0

IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tmp.##mytable t
    INNER JOIN nd.tblReqMatSum rms ON t.matnr = rms.matnr
    WHERE rms.isActive = 1
)    
BEGIN
    SET @result = 1; 
END
```

This is the execution plan:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1sdm3YBp

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to provide the execution plan, we can't assist with just the query as that contains no information about how the query is executed.

Comment: How can I get it?

Comment: Your favourite search engine?

Comment: execution plan added

Comment: Side note: You can do `declare @result int = 0` and remove the `else` part of your condition. This doesn't effect performance but just makes the code more readable.

Comment: @DaleK is that a website for execution plan optimization or do you mean that somehow I can paste the plan here, I just could not figure out how I can copy it. The only way I saw it was XML which was too long

Comment: I added the link above the images

Comment: It looks like tblReqMatSum  is for some reason assumed to have 1 rows with active = 1, but have many. wonder if your statistics are bad / non-existant. Clustered index scan means you don't have an active index. Also, you don't have any indexes on temp table. Finally, don't use global ##-tables, unless you know what you're doing. Probably it will help to create unique index on ##mytable-matnr.

Comment: You can add indexes to #temp and (I believe) #global_temp tables. In this case, an index on `##material268194(materialNumber)` may be what you need. Alternately, an index on `nd.tblRequestMaterialSummary(isActive, materialNumber)` might also help. Creating both indexes should allow SQL Server to resolve the `EXISTS()` with just those indexes and no table lookups.

Comment: Also why not do `if exists... set result = 0 else 1` - that will shortcut as soon as it finds a row.

Comment: Still I cannot understand why the subquery executes in 2-3 seconds and the IF EXISTS statement takes it to 10 mins, I added the indexes and it did not help much. I think the indexes are doing their job and that is why the subquery is taking a couple seconds only

Comment: The plan you've shown doesn't appear to be the "larger query" one? I'm confused by your question. In the plan you have shown there are no indexes, SQL Server is scanning your heap temp table and its estimate of rows is orders of magnitudes off, it's doing over half a billion lookups using an incorrect join type.

Comment: I just ran a test. I made a regular table and moved the rows from the global temp table and the entire query ran in no time, practically SSMS takes 22 milliseconds to run. I think I have to create a regular table using a stored procedure during the execution instead of the global temp table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> Note that `tmp.##mytable` is a global temporary table with no indexes, but it is almost always very small.

But it still has 1000 rows, and a naive nested loop (scanning the whole table each time) is getting you 589796 * 1000 rows being read.

Put an index on that temp table.

```sql
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CS ON ##material268194 ([material number])

UPDATE STATISTICS ##material268194 WITH FULLSCAN;
```

Preferably make this index unique if you can.

You also have a type mismatch between the two join columns. One is `nvarchar` the other is `varchar`. They should be the same, otherwise you get an implicit conversion, which affects cardinality estimations and therefore often affects plan shape.

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the answer! [material number] is always unique, but [material description] not all the time, do you recommend creating this index too? `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CS2 ON ##material268194 ([material number],[material description])` or creating an index on the [material description] will be just fine? Some other SPs join on [material description] and I wonder if I will get into the same problem

Comment: ignore "clustered" in the 2nd index as we cannot have more than one clustered index in a table

Comment: No just use `[material number]` as that will uniquely identify the row and you are using that in the query. As a clustered index it will include all other columns.

Comment: @DaleK I should have mentioned that I have another query that joins on [material description] and that is why I thought creating an index on that column would help too? or this one index on [material number] should do the job?

Comment: I did not write this answer :) Charlieface did

Comment: @Charlieface oops! I meant to ask you!

Comment: In that case it's hard to to say without seeing that query and its plan, as well as indicative cardinalities (# of distinct values and # of total rows) for the different columns. Possibly you could make a separate index for that query. If `material number` is also joined then it's unique and clustered anyway so it doesn't matter. The multi-column index you suggested will not work if you are only querying by `material description`.